# Alternative to Python pip bitcoin

Tags: segregated-witness, python

This Python pip package https://pypi.org/project/bitcoin/ was originally developed by Vitalik Buterin (that Ethereum guy) but is no longer maintained. Is there any alternative equivalent pip package which can also work with segwit addresses? Thanks.

Found this https://github.com/1200wd/bitcoinlib . And it is crap. Won't even install with pip or pipenv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this library by Peter Todd https://github.com/petertodd/python-bitcoinlib

Or pycoin https://github.com/richardkiss/pycoin

Comment: pycoin easier to use